# How can I run initialization code during axis2 startup?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have a 3rd party library that I use in my webapp. I need to call an init method from this library during axis2 startup.

I can't wait until the first request comes in - it must be done at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.my.YourServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Where `YourServletContextListener` has to implement `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` and provide your initialization code in the `contextInitialized(..)` method.

This method is called as soon as the servlet context is loaded.